# return data json from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

First of all I'm sorry if my English isn't totally correct. 
I'm learning to use json and I want to try with this simple code, where I insert *name* and *surname* and with Ajax I send them to a json struct for then show them in a table.
**ajax.php**

```
<form id="iscrizione">
    Nome: <input type="text" id="nome" /><br />
    Cognome: <input type="text" id="cognome" /></br >
    <input type="submit" id="invia" value="ISCRIVITI" />
</form>

<table>
    <tr><td>Nome: </td><td><span id="td_nome"></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cognome: </td><td><span id="td_cognome"></span></td></tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#iscrizione").submit(function(){
        var nome = $("#nome").val();
        var cognome = $("#cognome").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "json.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {nome: nome, cognome: cognome},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg){
                $("span#td_nome").html(msg.nome);
                $("span#td_cognome").html(msg.cognome);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert ("Chiamata Fallita");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**json.php**

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
$dati = array( 'nome'=>$_POST['nome'], 'cognome'=>$_POST['cognome'] );
echo json_encode($dati);
?>
```

Where are the mistakes? Because the outputs are shown for just a second and then they will disappear.
Thank you to everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On submitting form, it will reload page by default. We can cancel the submit action by calling [.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) on the event object or by returning false from our handler. Read more about [.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event.

1.On using returning false after ajax call.

```
$("#iscrizione").submit(function(){
    var nome = $("#nome").val();
    var cognome = $("#cognome").val();
    $.ajax({
        ....
        ....
    });
    return false; // add return false here
});
```

2.By using `event.preventDefault()`

```
$("#iscrizione").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();// use preventDefault() on event
    var nome = $("#nome").val();
    var cognome = $("#cognome").val();
    $.ajax({
        ....
        ....
    });
});
```

Comment: @RohanKumar The answer may have worked for him, but it is hardly correct and isn't a good habit to get into. With respect, it would be in the best interest of the community to put a bit more effort into your answer (I'm assuming with your rep that you know how to set up AJAX calls without submitting a form).  Particularly when you ask the OP to mark it as correct when the only criterion he has to go on is whether it solved his immediate problem or not.

Answer (score 2):

When you submit the form it will reload all page again, so assigned html visible for short time only.

Use **preventDefault()** function to overcome this situation.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#iscrizione").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    var nome = $("#nome").val();
    var cognome = $("#cognome").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "json.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {nome: nome, cognome: cognome},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg){
            $("span#td_nome").html(msg.nome);
            $("span#td_cognome").html(msg.cognome);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert ("Chiamata Fallita");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Either `return false` or `preventDefault()` will work, as the other two answers have described.  However, it's important to understand that you don't have to submit the form at all, and indeed it isn't best practice to do so.  After all, it doesn't make much sense to use HTML to submit the form and then disable the submit behavior in your code.  Especially when you don't have to.

AJAX was invented to overcome the problems (such as yours) that result when you reload the page.  The point about AJAX is that it gives you the ability to update your page with new data without reloading it.

So, the cleaner way to do what you want is to make your button simply a button, and call your code from the button's `click` event.  Have a look at this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
        Test
    </title>

    <!--jQuery file-->
    <script src="includes/jquery/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>    

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function showMyPHP() {
                var nome = $("#nome").val();
                var cognome = $("#cognome").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "json.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {nome: nome, cognome: cognome},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(msg){
                        $("#td_nome").html(msg.nome);
                        $("#td_cognome").html(msg.cognome);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert ("Chiamata Fallita");
                    }
                });
            }

            $('#invia').on('click', function(e, ui){
                showMyPHP();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="iscrizione">
    Nome: <input type="text" id="nome" /><br />
    Cognome: <input type="text" id="cognome" /></br >
    <button type="button" id="invia">"ISCRIVITI"</button>
</form>

<table>
    <tr><td>Nome: </td><td><span id="td_nome"></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cognome: </td><td><span id="td_cognome"></span></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see that we're not submitting the form at all here.  Rather, we're calling the AJAX through the button's click event.  You'll see that you get the results you're looking for, without resorting to using HTML to submit the form and then disabling the default submit behavior in code.